# SQL Round Up or No Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

I have the query

```
SELECT count(hh.[HouseholdIncome]) CountHH
    ,sum(try_convert(numeric(20), hh.[HouseholdIncome]) ) CountIncome
    ,sum(try_convert(numeric(20), hh.[HouseholdIncome]) ) / count(hh.[HouseholdIncome]) AnnualIncome
FROM [MergeData].[dbo].[HouseholdIncome] hh
```

I like to have the `AnnualIncome` result with round up or no decimal.

Comment: What is the datatype of `HouseholdIncome`?

Comment: why not cast the whole AnnualIncome as an integer or something suitable if you want the result to be a round number with no decimal?

Comment: Nvarchar type for this HouseholdIncome

Comment: `Nvarchar` for a numeric value? Please correct your database design!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to do integer division; this has the effect of removing the decimal part (so a value of `1.9`, for example, would become `1`).

```
sum(try_convert(int, hh.[HouseholdIncome]) ) / count(hh.[HouseholdIncome])
```

Comment: @Tsang . . . I think this truncates the value rather than rounding up -- and your question explicitly says rounding up.  That is why you should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `round()` SQL function e.g.

```
round(number, decimals)
```

Here is some documentation https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_round.asp

Comment: Hi, Diego. Providing supporting links with your answer is good, but w3schools has sort of a sketchy reputation on Stack Overflow. (I've seen answers get down-voted for linking to them...) You're better off providing links to database vendor documentation, in this case Microsoft's documentation for the SQL Server [ROUND()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

Comment: Great advice! Thank you, I'll be linking to the official documentation from now on